# HSA Data copy between RAM and GPU-RAM

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor

Reading the [wikipage about HSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogeneous_System_Architecture) found this block diagram.
Could not understand the benefits of passing pointer through PCI-ex

**Does this avoids data copying from system memory to graphics memory ?**

As far as I understand to process the content of the pointer the GPU will need it to be present in the graphics memory.

[image: block diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have separate graphics memory, but you're doing HSA, you have to somehow unify the address spaces.  The CPU can see graphics memory, mapped to physical address space.  And the GPU can access main memory via DMA.  You can set up the CPU and GPU with page tables that direct the same virtual addresses to the same place, which will require one of them to go (transparently) over the PCIe bus.

Where you save time and energy is that you don't have to copy everything you MIGHT want to access; the CPU and GPU access only the data they actually need to use.